# Network path not working for xlswritefig in Matlab

Tags: vba, matlab, excel

I am trying to open a workbook that is located on a network path using the function [xlswritefig](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24424-xlswritefig). I.e. the path does not start with the traditional letter such as `C:\`. Instead it looks as follows:

```
\\networkmain\folder\to
```

When I try to open the excel file on this folder in Matlab, I noticed that Excel adds the current path in front of the the path. I.e. if I am currently in folder 
C:\Matlab\ then Excel tries to open:

```
C:\Matlab\networkmain\folder\to
```

How can I prevent this from happening and redirect to the network path?

Comment: So what is the actual line of code you are calling where you encounter this problem?

Comment: `xlswritefig(hFig,'\\networkmain\folder\to',sheetname,xlcell)`

Comment: Thanks, I think it's clearer now. Consider also adding a comment to the relevant page on the File Exchange so that the author knows this is an issue which can cause unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the function `xlswritefig`. To solve for this issue, step into the function and change the following line of code (line 86):

```
%**op = invoke(Excel.Workbooks, 'open', [pwd filesep filename]);
op = invoke(Excel.Workbooks, 'open', filename);
```

Thus remove the `[pwd filesep]` part.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think UNC paths are supported in Matlab (at least the didn't use to). The simple way forward is to map your folder to a letter drive. It is possible to do this in Windows Explorer, but I tend to use `net use` in the command prompt. `net help use` will show you the syntax

Comment: Thanks, but not useful for me as I really need to work with Network paths. Every user has a different Letter on this computer pointing to this network path.

Comment: I noticed that UNC paths do work well with other Matlab built in functions. Its only that it breaks when using it in combination with Excel.

Comment: Letter drives are never good. Matlab isn't my forte. If you don't solve it in Matlab, I suggest an external script that copies the data to a local temp folder, called from within Matlab

Answer (score 1):

UNC (network) paths are not supported by MATLAB. However, here is a workaround which sets (and unsets) a network drive letter using the [`system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command.

```matlab
% Execute system command to assign drive letter 
system('net use Z: \\networkmain\folder\to');
% Perform actions under this drive
cd(Z:\);
% ...
% Unmount the drive
system('net use Z: /delete');
```

You could use some simple looping to find the next available drive letter, as the system call shoudn't override an existing drive letter.

Comment: Thank you. Good workarround. However, found the solution as in the function itself it was adding the fullpath as follows: `[pwd filesep filename]`. I replaced this with filename.

Comment: So it was an issue with a File Exchange function? Consider adding your own answer emphasising this - as that function isn't even the focus of your question so future users may assume this is a more generic problem.